# Data not being properly returned to controller from MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my model;

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace thinkBigHR.Models
{
public class Shift
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my controller;

```
// POST: Shifts/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Date, Employee")] Shift shift)
    {
        ClaimsIdentity user = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (user.HasClaim("Administrator", "true"))
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Shifts.Add(shift);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(shift);
        }
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
```

And this is my view.

```
@using thinkBigHR.Models;
@model thinkBigHR.Models.Shift
@{
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
var employees = db.Employees.ToList();
}
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Shift</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="Date" name="Date" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Assigned Employee:</label>
        <select name="Employee" class="form-control">
            @foreach (var item in employees)
            {
                <option value="@item.Id" id="Employee">@item.LegalName (@item.JobTitle)</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So it renders the view correctly, but I've set a breakpoint once the data is returned to the controller and it shows that only the date of the shift is being passed back, but not any details of the Employee chosen (returned as null).

Comment: You can bind a `<select>` element to a complex object - which is what `public Employee Employee { get; set; }` is. You need to have a property in your model (say) `int Employee` and bind to that. But why are you not strongly binding to your model using the html helpers `@Html.TextBoxFor()` and `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

Comment: You are using `employee` as name , I think it is a class or enum or some object. So inorder to pass data  You need to specify which field should contains the value like `employee[0].Id` or create some other property to pass the DDL value

Answer (score 0):

This is because the ASP.NET MVC default model binder can't figure out what to store in the Shift's Employee member.

Employee is a class and you need to create HTML controls named like it's members:

```
<input name="Employee.LegalName" />
<input name="Employee.JobTitle" />
```

Now after your form is posted the ASP.NET MVC model binder will know which input field belongs to which member of your Employee class within the Shift.

[Here you can find](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx) a detailed explanation on the default model binder.